# Android bluetooth le ScanResult isConnectable is not working

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

**isConnectable()** boolean method is not working. Working only in some devices like Pixel and Oneplus android 10. But other Android 10 devices like Samsung, Nokia it is not working

```
 private ScanCallback mScanCallback = new ScanCallback() {
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    @Override
    public void onScanResult(int callbackType, android.bluetooth.le.ScanResult result) {
        super.onScanResult(callbackType, result);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            if(result.isConnectable()) {
                mLeScanCallback.onLeScan(result.getDevice(), result.getRssi(),
                        result.getScanRecord().getBytes());
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

`ScanResult#isConnectable()` requires API O. In other cases it uses the legacy `ScanResult` data, which does not contain such information when unmasking.

You should change the condition to `if(!result.isLegacy() && result.isConnectable())`

Comment: Trying only in Android 10 devices, result.isLegacy() and result.isConnectable() both returning true. Not satisfying the if condition